# How to draw features in the right place on OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

The point is not drawn in the right place(OpenLayers)

I have tilesmap images and some coordinates(EPSG:5179). I'm trying to draw features by it in OpenLayers. But the coordinates are not drawn in the right place. For example, If I draw point in Korea, that point is drawn in Japan. And If I set option of center[0,0] in view, the map start in Japan. I think [0,0] coordinate is wrong on my tilesmap. Is there any way I can change the central coordinate or to draw the coordinates correctly(I already used transform function)?

Comment: use this syntax **coordinates= ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:5179', 'yourMapTileProjection')**

Answer (score 1):

[0, 0] in EPSG:5179 is somewhere south east of Taiwan.  To center on Korea you would need something like [1000000, 1800000] which is near Daejeon.  First check your projection definition is correct (see my example).  However if are using your own tiles you will need to know the extent or origin and resolutions of the tile grid to set up an OpenLayers tilegrid.

```js
proj4.defs("EPSG:5179","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127.5 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=2000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers : [ 
        new ol.layer.Tile({source : new ol.source.OSM()}),
    ],
    target : 'map',
    view : new ol.View({
        center: [1000000, 1800000],
        zoom: 7,
        projection: 'EPSG:5179'
    })
});
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```